# How to install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I want to install `gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf` or greater on **Ubuntu 12.04**, any suggestion?

The default one is `gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpectedly, I found a solution:

Add 13.10's apt source into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main universe
```

Then you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```